# Стоит ли удалять событие с элемента, перед его удалением?

Tags: javascript, html, события, javascript-events

В одном видео слышал, что удаляя элемент в котором есть событие мы не удаляем сам обработчик. Другими словами обработчик события продолжает работать, не смотря, что элемента нет. Хотел бы получить подтверждение или опровержение этим словам. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы не получите подтверждения этим словам, потому что они не соответствуют действительности.

Comment: "понимаю событие может находит**Ь**ся  в памяти" - что это значит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> удаляя элемент в котором есть событие мы не удаляем сам обработчик

Да, при удалении элемента из dom-дерева все обработчики на нём остаются:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.target.remove();
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.appendChild(e.target)
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

> Ну как я понимаю событие может находиться в памяти, но не выполняться

Выполняться тоже может:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.parentElement) {
    e.target.remove();
    setTimeout(function() { e.target.click() }, 500);
  } else {
    document.body.appendChild(e.target);
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

> Стоит ли удалять событие с элемента, перед его удалением?

В большинстве случаев нет. Если на элемент нет других ссылок, то он всё равно будет собран сборщиком мусора вместе с обработчиком:

```js
~function add() {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.textContent = "Click me";

  btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    btn.remove();
    setTimeout(add, 500);
  });

  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}();
```

Как видно в профайлере, выживших объектов от кликов кроме последнего нет:

[image: скриншот профайлера]

Впрочем, в IE8 действительно была проблема с утечками в некоторых подобных случаях.

---

Однако, если обработчик или элемент каким-то образом удерживается внешним кодом, то они будут сохранены до тех пор, пока это удерживание не исчезнет. Если есть какие-либо подписки на более долгоживущие объекты или события, то отписываться надо.

Поэтому при использовании фреймвёрка, имеющего жизненный цикл компонента, рекомендуется при уничтожении компонента отписаться от всего, на что подписался руками.